# What's with all the SharePoint hype?

Tags: sharepoint

SharePoint has been getting a lot of hype these days.  There are contracts/job postings all over the place looking for SharePoint experience.
There seems to be a big push on Web Part development, which is all well and good, but now I'm also hearing that entire web applications will be hosted within SharePoint. That sounds like it could easy introduce a lot of unnecessary overhead.

I figured I'd put this up for discussion amongst all of you. I'm eager to hear your thoughts.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Voted to close.

Comment: What is the point of a community wiki then?

Comment: the point of Community Wiki is to expose people who think this is a discussion site. Otherwise, they hide, and we can't find out who they are in order to correct them. Now that we know you think this site is for discussion, special steps can be taken to correct this aberration.

Comment: More and more companies are starting to turn to SharePoint instead of File Storage or even Exchange Public Folders. It also gives an internet presence in a neat, well formed CMS. Don't be surprised if it grows bigger and bigger each year.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SharePoint in itself is just a big ASP.NET web site that is highly, HIGHLY configurable.  Configurable almost to the point that it can become too complex.  However, as a SharePoint developer, it does deserve a lot of the hype it gets, especially if you were to build it from scratch.  Here are are some reasons why the the SharePoint overhead *can* be worth it:

- Web parts can be deployed to a production SharePoint site...without even taking it down for maintenance!  This allows rapid deployment of new functionality without the 3AM releases to make sure nobody is using the site.
- SharePoint is a development PLATFORM that contains seamless integration with Office Desktop Apps, Office Web Apps, Project Server, Team Foundation Server, Reporting...It greatly increases the collaboration of everyone involved...from software development to the CEO to the HR department to the...
- SharePoint takes care of the plumbing.  It lets you design workflows, web parts, reports, and more without you having to worry about the look and feel (once you have everything configured, of course...LOTS of configuring), having to connect to strange data sources AGAIN just to throw up a new report, having to redeploy the whole site, having to worry about a new piece of functionality (web part) taking down your entire site.

Those are some great things about it, but it definitely doesn't come without its flaws.  Again..the configuration is a beast, and changing even the slightest configuration can bring down SharePoint if you don't know what you're doing.  However, once you have it set up, deployment of new functionality and maintenance from a developer's standpoint is well, well worth it.

Answer (score 0):

My views on Sharepoint prior to 2010 hasn't been to good - it's ok for internal stuff... But apparently new version is supposed to be really smart but haven't had the chance to get into it yet. Although I am looking forward to getting in there.

Answer (score 0):

My views are quite skeptical about the 2013. SP2013 dev team should force browsers to support X-Frame-Options header as a security setting for iframes & JS or introduce a X-Frame-Trust header or do something else to allow communication between app part (which is an IFRAME with page in other domain) and parent page, to allow calls like so in app part scripts:

```
var selectedItems = window.parent.SP.ListOperation.Selection;
```

or provide an events / callback that invoked in iframe of app part when "context" like selected item was changed. 
Otherwise plenty of apps will not be impossible in new apps model.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it Sharepoint is an Excellent environment for Enterprise as it provides innumerable features Out of Box which are almost required for all organizations , be it document sharing, search , LOB system connectivity ,Work flows, Authentications, User Profile , People and extending and scaling out all these features to achieve the business logic which in a normal webapplication will be a task in itself to build all these things from scratch and then to extend it to achieve, Hence by reducing the human effort in the process and reducing the scope for errors.